# Duplicate Object Names in JSON

Tags: c#, json, ssis, .net-4.0

I am processing an API response that I am getting back that looks like this.
I am having an issue Deserializing part of it due to nesting levels having the same identifier and not able to name them the same in C# classes.

`"Dishonours": {
                  "Dishonours": [
                    {
                      "AccountID": 5292142,
                      "H1": "Dishonours",
                      "H2": "Dishonours",
                      "H3": "",
                      "SH1": "",
                      "Description": "{No Unique Description} (DIR DR RVSL,DIR DR RVSL FEE)",
                      "Count": 2,
                      "FrequencyDescription": "Infrequent Same Day",
                      "FrequencyDuration": "",
                      "FrequencyDurationDate": "24Oct",
                      "FrequencyWeekday": "",
                      "FrequencyAmount": 47.2,
                      "FrequencyAmountRange": "(6-88)",
                      "TotalAmount": 94.4,
                      "TotalInAmount": 88.4,
                      "TotalOutAmount": 6,
                      "MonthlyAmount": 0,
                      "GroupID": "0-1130",
                      "Display": "{No Unique Description}",
                      "FrequencyExactness": "Infrequent",
                      "FrequencyPeriod": "Same Day",
                      "ScoreEmployer": null,
                      "ScoreDirCr": null,
                      "ScoreWeekday": null,
                      "ScoreFrequency": null,
                      "ScoreAmount": null,
                      "ScoreTotal": 0
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "High Risk Merchants": {
                  "High Risk Merchants": [
                    {
                      "AccountID": 5292142,
                      "H1": "High Risk Merchants",
                      "H2": "High Risk Merchants",
                      "H3": "",
                      "SH1": "",
                      "Description": "{NO MATCH}",
                      "Count": null,
                      "FrequencyDescription": null,
                      "FrequencyDuration": null,
                      "FrequencyDurationDate": null,
                      "FrequencyWeekday": null,
                      "FrequencyAmount": null,
                      "FrequencyAmountRange": null,
                      "TotalAmount": null,
                      "TotalInAmount": null,
                      "TotalOutAmount": null,
                      "MonthlyAmount": null,
                      "GroupID": null,
                      "Display": null,
                      "FrequencyExactness": null,
                      "FrequencyPeriod": null,
                      "ScoreEmployer": null,
                      "ScoreDirCr": null,
                      "ScoreWeekday": null,
                      "ScoreFrequency": null,
                      "ScoreAmount": null,
                      "ScoreTotal": null
                    }
                  ]
                }`

I have declared my C# classes like this but I am still getting a null reference error because it wont pick up the nested tag.

This is how I have deserialized it to this point.

```
private RootObjectContent DeserializeReportContent(string reportAttachmentContent)
{
    RootObjectContent attachedReportContent = null;

    string reportContentString = null;

    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(rptJsonContent.Replace(@"\", ""));

    using (StringReader contentReader = new StringReader(reportAttachmentContent.Replace(@"\", "")))
    {
        reportContentString = contentReader.ReadToEnd().ToString();
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(reportContentString);

    JavaScriptSerializer returnRptContent = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var serialContentJsonStr = returnRptContent.Serialize(reportContentString);

    attachedReportContent = returnRptContent.Deserialize<RootObjectContent>(reportContentString.Replace(@"\", ""));

    return attachedReportContent;

}
```

I am restricted to using SSIS in Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0) and as such cant use Newtonsoft version 10.0.0.0.

Is there anyway around this?

```
public class Dishonour
{
    [JsonProperty("AccountID")]
    public int? AccountID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("H1")]
    public string H1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("H2")]
    public string H2 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("H3")]
    public string H3 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SH1")]
    public string SH1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Count")]
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyDescription")]
    public string FrequencyDescription { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyDuration")]
    public string FrequencyDuration { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyDurationDate")]
    public string FrequencyDurationDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyWeekday")]
    public string FrequencyWeekday { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyAmount")]
    public decimal? FrequencyAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyAmountRange")]
    public string FrequencyAmountRange { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalAmount")]
    public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalInAmount")]
    public decimal? TotalInAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalOutAmount")]
    public decimal? TotalOutAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("MonthlyAmount")]
    public decimal? MonthlyAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GroupID")]
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Display")]
    public string Display { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyExactness")]
    public string FrequencyExactness { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyPeriod")]
    public string FrequencyPeriod { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreEmployer")]
    public int? ScoreEmployer { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreDirCr")]
    public int? ScoreDirCr { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreWeekday")]
    public int? ScoreWeekday { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreFrequency")]
    public int? ScoreFrequency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreAmount")]
    public int? ScoreAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreTotal")]
    public int? ScoreTotal { get; set; }
}

public class Dishonours
{
    [JsonProperty("Dishonours")]
    public List<Dishonour> Dishonour { get; set; }
}

public class HighRiskMerchant
{
    [JsonProperty("AccountID")]
    public int? AccountID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("H1")]
    public string H1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("H2")]
    public string H2 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("H3")]
    public string H3 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("SH1")]
    public string SH1 { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Count")]
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyDescription")]
    public string FrequencyDescription { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyDuration")]
    public string FrequencyDuration { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyDurationDate")]
    public string FrequencyDurationDate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyWeekday")]
    public string FrequencyWeekday { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyAmount")]
    public double? FrequencyAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyAmountRange")]
    public string FrequencyAmountRange { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalAmount")]
    public double? TotalAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalInAmount")]
    public double? TotalInAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("TotalOutAmount")]
    public double? TotalOutAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("MonthlyAmount")]
    public double? MonthlyAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("GroupID")]
    public string GroupID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Display")]
    public string Display { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyExactness")]
    public string FrequencyExactness { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("FrequencyPeriod")]
    public string FrequencyPeriod { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreEmployer")]
    public int? ScoreEmployer { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreDirCr")]
    public int? ScoreDirCr { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreWeekday")]
    public string ScoreWeekday { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreFrequency")]
    public string ScoreFrequency { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreAmount")]
    public double? ScoreAmount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ScoreTotal")]
    public int? ScoreTotal { get; set; }
}

public class HighRiskMerchants
{
    [JsonProperty("High Risk Merchants")]
    public List<HighRiskMerchants> HighRiskMerchant { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand your problem.  Do you really have duplicated property names within the same object as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20714160/3744182) or are you talking about wanting to flatten the nested hierarchy `"{ Dishonours": {"Dishonours": [ ...] } }` ?

Comment: Yes that is correct. It is not the greatest data.

Comment: Wait - which is correct?  Duplicated names or nesting?

Comment: Nesting sorry. poorly worded.