# How to deserialize JSON dictionary with duplicated, empty keys?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I'm using a custom API and part of the response is explanation of the results which looks like this:

```
"explain": {
    "": "qwer",
    "": "asd"
}
```

As you can see the keys are empty so while trying to deserialize it to Dictionary using `Newtonsoft.Json` I get a dictionary containing only 1 value as each one overrides the previous.

Comment: Where did this custom API come from?  Why would field names be blank?  How would you know what field value is referencing?  The order in which they appear?

Comment: Either deserialize it using one of the other values as key, or deserialize it to a list of Tuple, or KeyValuePair or something.

Comment: I'm using solr api and I really don't know why do the return data this way. It is sorted by the order in which the searched documents are returned as the explanation is for the search

Comment: Json.NET has no problem deserializing an empty dictionary key.  The real problem is dealing with the key duplication.  For that, see [How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20714160).  Note that duplicated keys are not recommended, according to the [JSON RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4): *When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.  Many implementations report the last name/value pair only...*