# Should accept duplicate properties of Json in Deserialize c#

Tags: json, json.net

I have mentioned the JSON format below. Both the address should be bound separately in the object, not combined.

```
{
  "Address": [
    {
      "Parameters": "Home",
      "Key": "home_add",
      "Value": "ABC"
    }
  ],
  "Address": [
    {
      "Parameters": "Office",
      "Key": "office_add",
      "Value": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714160/how-to-deserialize-json-with-duplicate-property-names-in-the-same-object)

Comment: And what would you bind the duplicate properties to?  In other words, what is your model?