# Creating json object with duplicate keys in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, generic-collections

I am creating a json string by serializing an object in C# (using Newtonsoft) to pass to a third party charting library, so have no control over the structure I need to create. The structure requires an object with duplicate keys, something like;

```
{ "color": "dd3333",
  "linewidth": 2,
  "dataset": [ 3,4,5,6 ],
  "dataset": [ 5,6,7,8]
}
```

I'm struggling to get the output I want. I was using a dictionary, but have just come across the need for duplicate keys, which scuppers that. I've had a look at creating my own object to support duplicate keys (starting with these suggestions [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries)) but am still struggling to get them to serialize to the format I need.

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: That would be invalid JSON. The major JSON serializers won't produce it. Keys must be unique. If you can, redefine it to use an array of arrays: `"datasets": [[ 3,4,5,6 ], [ 5,6,7,8 ]]`  Also, strict JSON compliance requires quoted key names.

Comment: I'd like to recommend against this.  According to [RFC 8259](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#section-4): *The names within an object SHOULD be unique.*.  If you really need this, you will need to create your own custom `JsonConverter` for the containing class.  An example of custom parsing (not serialization) of duplicate keys is here: [How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20714160/3744182).

Comment: Thanks for the comment on the names not being in quotes, that was just my mistake, they should have been. I've edited the question. As I said above, I have no choice in providing this structure, I am providing data to a third party app and that's the defined structure. I agree it's not ideal, but hey ho, I'm stuck with it. As to whether it's valid JSON, that seems up for debate. A good discussion on this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832701/does-json-syntax-allow-duplicate-keys-in-an-object

Comment: Thanks for the comments on deserializing, I'd already seen that. Unfortunately I want to serialize the object, the third party app de-serializes, so not my problem!

Comment: @Nick that discussion (Feb 2014) is from before RFC 8259 (Dec 2017) stated that _"the names within an object SHOULD be unique."_ What library are you using? Requiring something that violates an explicitly stated standard is bad design.

Comment: I'd rather not name and shame the components we're using Pranav, with the exception of this issue they've been great. I suspect the particular data definition was defined before this change in the standards and they're stuck with it now there's a userbase out there.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, I created a dictionary object that accepted duplicate keys (copied from [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries)), and added a JsonConverter to control how the object was serialized;

```
  public class MultiMap<TKey, TValue>
  {
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>> storage;

    public MultiMap()
    {
      storage = new Dictionary<TKey, IList<TValue>>();
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
      if (!storage.ContainsKey(key)) storage.Add(key, new List<TValue>());
      storage[key].Add(value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys
    {
      get { return storage.Keys; }
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
      return storage.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public IList<TValue> this[TKey key]
    {
      get
      {
        if (!storage.ContainsKey(key))
          throw new KeyNotFoundException(
              string.Format(
                  "The given key {0} was not found in the collection.", key));
        return storage[key];
      }
    }
  }
```

The JsonConverter object was as follows (I didn't bother with the read as I didn't need it, but it could be easily implemented);

```
public class MultiMapJsonConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter
  {
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
      return objectType == typeof(MultiMap<TKey, TValue>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      throw new NotImplementedException("Unnecessary because CanRead is false. The type will skip the converter.");
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
      get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
      writer.WriteStartObject();
      MultiMap<TKey, TValue> m = (MultiMap<TKey, TValue>)value;

      foreach (TKey key in m.Keys)
      {
        foreach (TValue val in m[key])
        {
          writer.WritePropertyName(key.ToString());
          JToken.FromObject(val).WriteTo(writer);
        }
      }
      writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
  }
```

With this defined , the following code;

```
var mm = new MultiMap<string, object>();
mm.Add("color", "dd3333");
mm.Add("linewidth", 2);
mm.Add("dataset", new int[] { 3,4,5,6 });
mm.Add("dataset", new int[] { 5,6,7,8 });
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mm, new JsonConverter[] { new MultiMapJsonConverter<string, object>() });
```

gives me the json output;

```
{"color":"dd3333","linewidth":2,"dataset":[3,4,5,6],"dataset":[5,6,7,8]}
```