# Deserialize json to c# class issue cause of json data is array or not

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I got a `JSON` data like below and the `FlightSegment` object type seems one of the `Array` and the other one is not.

When I create an object as `FlightSegment[]`, i am getting this error :

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'WA_2_0_RS.FlightSegment[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or `List<T>`) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. `JsonObjectAttribute` can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

What it should be as c# class?

```
{
    "FlightSegment": {
        "DepartureAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "ESB"
        },
        "Ticket": "eTicket",
        "ArrivalAirport": {
            "LocationCode": "ADB"
        },
        "DateChangeNbr": false,
        "StopQuantity": "0",
        "CodeshareInd": false,
        "Equipment": {
            "Value": "UNKNOWN_PLANE",
            "AirEquipType": "***"
        },
        "DepartureDateTime": "2020-12-22T20:10:00.000+03:00",
        "ArrivalDateTime": "2020-12-22T21:30:00.000+03:00",
        "FlightNumber": "****",
        "OperatingAirline": {
            "CompanyShortName": "**"
        },
        "JourneyDuration": "P0DT1H20M0.000S"
    }
}, {
    "FlightSegment": [{
            "DepartureAirport": {
                "LocationCode": "ESB"
            },
            "Ticket": "eTicket",
            "ArrivalAirport": {
                "LocationCode": "SAW"
            },
            "DateChangeNbr": false,
            "StopQuantity": "0",
            "GroundDuration": "P0DT0H45M0.000S",
            "CodeshareInd": false,
            "Equipment": {
                "Value": "A320-200",
                "AirEquipType": "320"
            },
            "DepartureDateTime": "2020-12-22T12:05:00.000+03:00",
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2020-12-22T13:10:00.000+03:00",
            "FlightNumber": "****",
            "OperatingAirline": {
                "CompanyShortName": "**"
            },
            "JourneyDuration": "P0DT1H5M0.000S"
        }, {
            "DepartureAirport": {
                "LocationCode": "SAW"
            },
            "Ticket": "eTicket",
            "ArrivalAirport": {
                "LocationCode": "ADB"
            },
            "DateChangeNbr": false,
            "StopQuantity": "0",
            "CodeshareInd": false,
            "Equipment": {
                "Value": "UNKNOWN_PLANE",
                "AirEquipType": "73D"
            },
            "DepartureDateTime": "2020-12-22T13:55:00.000+03:00",
            "ArrivalDateTime": "2020-12-22T15:00:00.000+03:00",
            "FlightNumber": "****",
            "OperatingAirline": {
                "CompanyShortName": "**"
            },
            "JourneyDuration": "P0DT1H5M0.000S"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can try https://json2csharp.com/ just paste your json then get class for parsing the data.

Comment: That is not a valid JSON document, so you'll not likely be able to parse it with any JSON serializer. You'll probably need to read it manually, if you cannot change the JSON structure

Comment: yes i did, but it creates FlightSegment as an "object". But object is also known type FlightSegment. I am asking that when i use it as FlightSegment and FlightSegment[] or List<FlightSegment> then it returns deserialize error like my first comment.

Comment: It comes up often as a question, of how to parse json that is [sometimes one thing and sometimes another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224697/deserializing-json-when-sometimes-array-and-sometimes-object)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto yes also i am thinking like you and asked source company to change their data as valid. But i don't believe that they will not change their Json structure.

Comment: @CaiusJard Yeah, something like that could be applied here, but the JSON structure needs to be fixed first (right now there are 2 top-level objects which isn't valid)

Comment: You may look at this question [How to deserialize JSON with duplicate property names in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714160/how-to-deserialize-json-with-duplicate-property-names-in-the-same-object)

Comment: @Ibnelaiq Well, try it with the JSON provided, you'll see that it cannot generate the correct structure. Please refrain from adding comments like that if you haven't validated whether the JSON can be parsed in the first place

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto whenever I see that (2+ top level obj) I assume that someone has accidentally stripped off the `[ ]` they got back from the service. Worth calling out tho; at the very least some client side patching might be needed if they won't change the output

Comment: You may declare your `FlightSegment` property as a `List<FlightSegment>` and use `SingleOrArrayConverter<FlightSegment>` from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182).  In fact I think your question is a duplicate, agree?

Answer (score 0):

@Caius Jard's solution has fixed my issue.

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224697/deserializing-json-when-sometimes-array-and-sometimes-object)